# increase rows of table

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>//1
        //some control server side  
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>//2
            //some control server side
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>//3
           //some control server side
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i like when increase hegiht content of td.1 then increase hegiht of td.2 and td.3 automaticly.

Comment: Can you please make your question clearer? It's difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: I think the OP wants "When TD 1s height increases, have TD 2 and 3 increase at the same time." Although I could be mistaken,

Comment: @GodIsLive: Are you sure you mean _height_ and not _width_? Since it's a table, the increase in height should happen automatically... If you want the contents of each table cell to line up, then use `<td valign="top">` or `<td style="vertical-align: top">` (style setting can be moved to a class)

Comment: Please clarify your question or it will be closed due to being ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that easily with CSS.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell-class"> cell 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell-class"> cell 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell-class"> cell 3 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in your .css file, do:

```
.cell-class { height: 40px; }
```

When you increase the height in your css, the three cells will automatically increase height.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner (and faster) way to increase the height of all cells would be:

HTML

```
<table id="my_table">
    <tr>
        <td> cell 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> cell 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> cell 1 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#my_table tr td
{
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Looking back at this it would be even better (from a content perspective) to add padding to the td's: padding: 15px 0;.